# GWT Cell Tree, Selecting too many options!

Tags: java, gwt, tree, cell

I am using a gwt cell tree and I want only one node to be selected in the whole tree but many nodes are being selected.

I am also trying this

```
S1= new SelectionModel();......
S1.setSelected(S1.getSelected(),false); but using this technique nothing is being selected.
```

I am having the following problem:[image]

Can someone help??

Comment: Maybe add some more sourcecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe SingleSelectionModel helps you;

```
SingleSelectionModel selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel();
```

See [Google Example 2](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/cellview/CellTreeExample2.java&q=celltree%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=7)
to [SingleSelectionModel](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.1.0/gwt-servlet-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/view/client/SingleSelectionModel.html) usage.

Comment: I am using the single selection model itself

Answer (score 0):

Code looks weird to me, because you firstly get selected object with `S1.getSelected()` command and then kinda re-select same object, so no wonder that nothing happens. Instead `S1.getSelected()` pass object that you want to select.

Comment: When I do S1.getSelected(), I am getting the current selected object. So before selecting a new object, I am just trying to get the currently selected object, then unselect this object

Comment: Simple selection model allows only one object to be selected at a time so you should just select new object, there is no need to unselect old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a key provider to the selection model like this

```
selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<NamedObject>(new ProvidesKey<NamedObject>() {

        @Override
        public Object getKey(NamedObject item) {
            return item.getKey();
        }
    });
```

This will uniquely identify the nodes in the tree.